# Como abrir pagina dentro da div e fazer que os inputs dessa pagina interna funcionar?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Fiz uma pagina `index` que chama outra pagina dentro da `div`. Mas me deparei com um simples problema: a pagina aparece dentro da `div` da pagina `index`, onde tenho com campo de pesquisa, só que ao clicar no botão ou da um <kbd>enter</kbd> no campo, não carrega a função. Fiz um teste com essa pagina que chama dentro da `div` separada e os `inputs` carregam, mas chamando ela dentro da `div` da pagina index não carregar a função.

Meu código esta abaixo:

```
//esse javascript é o que chama a pagina dentro da <div>
<script>
function display_c(){
    setInterval('getInfo()',30000);
}
function getInfo(){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("conteudo").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "MRB_Dados.php?op=<?php echo $op;?>", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

$.post('MRB.php',function(html){
    $('#coteudo').html(html);
});
</script>

//aqui é a <div> que vai receber a pagina.

<div id="conteudo"></div>

//e esse é os inputs que eu chamo da outra pagina que vai aparecer dentro da <div>.

<section>
   <table border="0" align="center">
       <tr>
        <td width="300">
          <input type="search" placeholder="" id="bs-prod"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="str" id="str" value="aqm"/>
              <input type="hidden" name="str" id="str" value="aqm"/></td>
         <td>
         &nbsp;<input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value=" Pesquisar ">
                <input type="hidden" name="pesquisar" value="sim">
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </section>
```

Comment: Poderia colocar o HTML das duas páginas?

Comment: Se você tiver colocando funções JavaScript / jQuery relacionadas a página que será chamada na página principal, não vai funcionar mesmo. O JavaScript irá procurar os elementos especificados e, como não encontrou, irá dar erro. Você tem que chamar a página e, com ela, o conteúdo JavaScript relacionado. Existe uma técnica para burla isso, mas é complicada e pouco eficiente.

Comment: Clayderson você poderia me manda um exemplo de como chamar a função javascript junto com a pagina por favor